# Facebook Graph api limits

Tags: facebook, graph

I need to get the amount of Likes a Facebook page has periodically, as realtime as possible.

The original plan is to use a cronjob with a call to the Graph API. 
http://graph.facebook.com/SomeCrazyPage

Now my question is.. 
What's the time/amount limit for these calls? or How many/often calls can I make to the graph without being 'blocked'?

This is not my Facebook Page, and this is not intended to be used as a FB app, but to be stored in database to monitor the likes until this page reaches 20K likes.

Any other suggestions, or a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need that info in realtime?

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question, I would say you only need to update every day at most, it is unlikely that you will have such a massive boost in likes in a day to make that worthwhile. It would also put extra stress on your own server.

Comment: The realtime need (or as close as realtime as possible) is because the 20K should trigger some event in a website... then there is this "thermometer" thing on this site..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook's [realtime updates API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

And subscribe for the page likes event. So whenever there is a new like for the page you will automatically be reported about the change.

So you dont need to keep pinging to the Facebook servers all the time.

And also you dont need to worry about any Rate limiting.

Comment: I'll read into this, but as I said, I'm not the administrator of the FB page.

Comment: Please read the complete doc for Realtime updates. You dont need to be the Admin on the page